# Quaggy.js library - Barcode scanner

Tags: javascript, barcode

I have found this javascript library which is used to locate and decode barcodes using a video livestream through the camera (via the browser). Now this library uses a target element in order to display the camera view, and draws stuff on it, like green recentagles when detecting a barcode.

My question is, how can I use this library to make the scanner work in the background, like.. how to disable the feature of drawing this? I just want it to run on the background and print a console.log whenever a barcode is decoded (there is a callback that gets triggered whenever a barcode is decoded).

Like.. what I can do is.. make the target element "hidden", but I don't think it is a really good idea because the library will be functioning and working to draw things on it while it is not visible, which is wasteful.

Thanks in advance, Ahmed.

Comment: if you want a library to not do what it does, then you need to rewrite the library to not do what you don't want it to do - or search the documentation of that library to see if you can make it behave the way you want - otherwise - use a different library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit `live_w_locator.js` on  `Quagga.onProcessed` function, you can delete/comment all part of that.
Then into `Quagga.onDetected` you can play with that and use how you want ( the code will be into var name code `:)` )

Comment: Is this file in the library source folders (node_module)?

Comment: Go [here](https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS/tree/master/example) and download the files.

Comment: So this file is just an example, that means that the library doesn't  draw by default,? Like if I install it and don't set an HTML element when initing the library then things would be good?

Comment: It's how you "must" use it but you can edit it. in my personal experience with this plugin i used their file locator directly and changed some things for example i redirected directly after seeing what code it was

Comment: I found this (https://codepen.io/teguh-rijanandi/pen/YzwZMqo) example, what I did is that I removed the 'target' property from the Quaggy.Init function, and cleared the onProcessed callback. The camera-view was gone, but is it a good solution?